# C++ inherit from a template using subclass

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, nested-class

I want to create a parent class `Foo` inheriting from a template with argument its own nested class `Sub` but without get `Sub` out of `Foo`, do you have a solution ?

```
class Foo : public Bar<Sub>
{
    class Sub
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks

SOLUTION : There is no "common" way to do this so the best solution is to bring the nested class out.

Comment: No, you have circular dependencies, hence it is impossible

Comment: Are you sure ? `class Foo : Bar<Foo>` is possible so why not the subclass ?

Comment: @56ka Because in the `Bar<Foo>` case, the name `Foo` is already in scope, which is not the case in the `Bar<Sub>` case.

Comment: Why does `Sub` need to be inside `Foo`?

Comment: @lethal-guitar In my case it does not really needs to because it is only a data structure but I was interested to know if there were a way to do it.

Comment: Can we call it a nested class rather than a subclass? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible directly, simply because the name `Sub` is not (and cannot be) in scope when you want to use it. If you cannot simply move the class out (you need it accessible as a member), you can work around it by moving the nested class out with an insanely unique name, providing a `typedef` for it inside the class and, if necessary, making it a `friend`:

```
class Foo_Sub_ce60eba1_67fa_48a3_b5f5_fce89d717839
{
  // Contents...
};

class Foo : Bar<Foo_Sub_ce60eba1_67fa_48a3_b5f5_fce89d717839>
{
  typedef Foo_Sub_ce60eba1_67fa_48a3_b5f5_fce89d717839 Sub;
  friend Sub;
};
```

Comment: Interesting, so there is no "common" way to do what I wanted so the best solution is to bring the subclass out. Thanks